# Group keys of an object in array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array :

```
let x = [{name: 'x1', value: 2}, {name: 'x2', value: 3}, {name: 'y1', value: 4}, {name: 'z1', value: 1}];
```

I need to group few keys based on some condition and get their sum

```
res = [{
name: ['x1, y1'],
value: 6
},
{
name: [x2],
value: 3
},
{
name: [z1],
value: 1
}]
```

Comment: Typically this is called 'grouping', not clubbing, if I understand your question. Why are x1 and y1 in the same group, but not z1?

Comment: What's the logic for grouping here? Please create a [mcve] with compilable input, output and the code you've tried.

Comment: For now grouping is  based on hard-coded value (In this scenario x1 and y1)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a number of grouped items and consider them as separate groups.

```js
const
    groups = [['x1', 'y1']],
    data = [{ name: 'x1', value: 2 }, { name: 'x2', value: 3 }, { name: 'y1', value: 4 }, { name: 'z1', value: 1 }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { name, value }) => {
        const key = groups.find(a => a.includes(name))?.join('|') || name;
        r[key] ??= { name: [], value: 0 };
        r[key].name.push(name);
        r[key].value += value;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that this way:

```
let res = [
    {
        name: ["x1", "y1"],
        value: 0
    },
    [...]
]

res.forEach(group => {
    x.forEach(row => {
        if (group.name.indexOf(row.name) !== -1) {
            group.value += row.value;
        }
    });
})
```